# How to remove JQuery session in php page?

Tags: jquery, session

I am using https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin/blob/master/README.markdown to use session in javascript file. And its working perfectly.

I have a php page which will do logout the user thus destroying all session including that of JQuery session.

```
if ( isset($_GET["logout"]) && !empty($_GET["logout"]) ) {

    session_destroy();//destroying php session
    //destroying jquery session
    echo '<script>';
        echo "$.session.remove('messagearchive');";
    echo '</script>';
 }
```

I can destroy php session but I cannot destroy jquery session. Please help me with any solution.

Comment: :))) where is the echo in front of  `$.session.remove('messagearchive');`?

Comment: I tried with echo also. Its not working.

Comment: check your localstorage see if the value is still there

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: did you appended the js library to your page?

Comment: Yes I did append library.

Comment: have you tried wraping your code in a document ready statement?

Comment: did you try `$.session.clear();`?

Comment: I just tried `$.session.clear();` And still didn't clean session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128802/discussion-between-tapaljor-and-madalin-ivascu).